# How do I test a Facebook page tab app without creating a public page for it?

Tags: facebook

I'm developing a FB page tab app, and I want to provide my client a URL for testing the app. I don't have a page specifically for this app, nor do I want to create one - the test versions of the app should remain private. What is the normal process for testing page tab apps privately in this manner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

Go to your application: developers.facebook.com/apps
open your app, on left side there is a section called advanced (settings->advanced),
just click on that and you will find  create a facebook page option,
you can create a facebook page and after creating,
you can set setting for publish or unpublish.

Comment: is this option still available? i don't see on my advanced settings.

Comment: Yes it is, but nowadays you can find it under "App Details" -> "Contact info".

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the `Sandbox Mode` in your app settings.
If you want to give other users access to the app, you need to add them as developers or testers in the `Roles` settings.